# Errors when publishing my nuxtjs website on SSR mode

Tags: node.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I have some issues while trying to publish a nuxtjs site. Usually, I was using the generate command, but for this one I need to go full SSR, so I'm going for nuxt start.

But after building and starting the app, it's a mess. The build goes perfectly in the console, and the application start. The problem is when I try to access the site, it loads partially, but I got all these errors in the browser:

```
manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
vendor.7519259bf7bdf608079e.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
app.a5cb9356f53306f973dc.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
default.1f3ad14df16ee86595af.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
index.260dc65b69022a31ad58.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/_nuxt/pages/spot/_slug.e57cc2e78d8e0b160fe7.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
default.1f3ad14df16ee86595af.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
index.260dc65b69022a31ad58.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
vendor.7519259bf7bdf608079e.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
app.a5cb9356f53306f973dc.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Nothing seems wrong during the build. When I use nuxt start, I get this:

```
$ nuxt start
  nuxt:axios BaseURL: http://localhost:3042/api (Browser: /api) +0ms

  OPEN  http://localhost:3042
```

Here's my server conf file:

```
# Site global
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    access_log  off;

    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3042/;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf;
        root /var/www/mywebsite/site;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|srt|swf)$ {
        root /var/www/mywebsite/site/;
        expires 30d;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mywebsite.com/privkey.pem;
}

# Redirection
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

And my nuxt config file:

```
    const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
    mode: 'universal',

    loading: { color: '#bb2b4d' },

    router: {
        linkActiveClass: '-active',
        base: '/'
    },

    css: ['@/assets/icons/css/icons.css', '@/assets/snickles/snickles.css'],

    plugins: ['~plugins/vue-filters.js', '~plugins/vue-modal.js'],

    minify: {
        removeEmptyAttributes: false,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        conservativeCollapse: true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeTagWhitespace: false,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    },

    modules: [

        '@nuxtjs/axios'
    ],

    axios: {

    },

    env: {
        api: {
            spots: `https://rest.mywebsite.com/spots`
        }
    },

    proxy: {
    },

    build: {
        extend(config, ctx) {
            // Run ESLint on save
            if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
                config.module.rules.push({
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                    loader: 'eslint-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/
                })
            }
        }
    },

    postcss: [require('autoprefixer')],

    vendor: ['moment', 'vue-js-modal']
}
```

Did I forget anything?
The most strange part is that it works perfectly well when I do the same on my own pc and not on my server. I checked the npm and node versions, they are the same (latest to date). Also, if testing with a demo template from NuxtJS, it works perfectly with the exact same server configuration.

By the way, the server is a debian 8, with all packages up to date.

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Edit: If of any use, the error log:

```
2018/02/14 19:12:54 [error] 12981#12981: *239930 open() "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/pages/spot/_slug.e57cc2e78d8e0b160fe7.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx., server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /_nuxt/pages/spot/_slug.e57cc2e78d8e0b160fe7.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
2018/02/14 19:12:57 [error] 12981#12981: *239930 open() "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /_nuxt/manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
2018/02/14 19:12:57 [error] 12981#12981: *239930 open() "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/vendor.7519259bf7bdf608079e.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /_nuxt/vendor.7519259bf7bdf608079e.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
2018/02/14 19:12:57 [error] 12981#12981: *239930 open() "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/app.a5cb9356f53306f973dc.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /_nuxt/app.a5cb9356f53306f973dc.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
```

Again, it’s working perfectly fine with other nuxt projects, with a similar configuration. Indeed it can’t find these files in this folder, as they’re not in it — which is perfectly normal. It’s up to the app to get the routes to these files, which it usually does pretty well, with the **same directory output** (as I said, it’s supposed not to be in a _nuxt folder).

Thanks.

Comment: What does the error_log say?

Comment: You mean, the nginx error log? Nothing useful, just that the files don’t exist, same as the console log.

Its looking at these files in the .nuxt/ directory, and they are in .nuxt/dist/ (default configuration). But even if I duplicate the files in the .nuxt/ directory, it keep saying it can't reach them.

Comment: LOL, so, there's valuable information of where nginx is looking for these files in the log files, as opposed to think where it should look, and you consider it as "nothing useful"?!  Good luck with such an approach!  Noone will be able to help you if you without such information!

Comment: @cnst Well, I'm not new to this. The titles refers to NuxtJS, not Nginx, because I know that the problem is not coming from my Nginx configuration, which I added in my post to have this point clear from the start.

It’s going perfectly with a demo template from NuxtJS community, and the output is exactly the same (.nuxt folder, dist folder inside, etc.), and it's working perfectly without having any changes in my Nginx configuration. So this is a problem with my NuxtJS app and/or config, unrelated to Nginx.

Comment: @cnst but fair enough, I’ve added the logs to the original post. Please let me know if it helps you understanding the problem origin.

Comment: so, these files — like /var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js — do they exist?!  Under the same path?!

Comment: No, and that’s the point: they should be. The app build don’t create the files where it will look at them. That’s the whole mystery. As a basic example, if you set a simple nodejs project that will build all your files in a "dist" folder, when you start the main js file in the root folter, and it will look at the files in the dist folder. Here, the build create the files in a certain folder (/var/www/mywebsite/site/.nuxt/dist), and seems look in another (/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt). But the root folder is "site", where Nginx points.

Comment: So, are they created anywhere?  If you run `find / -type f -name "manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js"`, do any results return?

Comment: Yes, in "/var/www/mywebsite/site/.nuxt/dist", which is the default path set by Nuxt.js. And when the app start, it look strangely into "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was tagged with `nginx`, so, here's the nginx way of solving the problem.

After the troubleshooting through the comments, you report receiving the following in your `error_log`:

`2018/02/14 19:12:57 [error] 12981#12981: *239930 open() "/var/www/mywebsite/site/_nuxt/manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: www.mywebsite.com, request: "GET /_nuxt/manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.mywebsite.com/"`

Subsequently, running `find / -type f -name manifest.3a7efd91c5f63f114507.js`, or similar, results in the corresponding file being located in `/var/www/mywebsite/site/.nuxt/dist`.

As such, your nginx configuration is wrong, because you make it look for these things in the incorrect folder — your config has `root /var/www/mywebsite/site/;` instead.

The ***proper way*** would may be to use a prefix-based `location` together with the [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) directive:

```
location /_nuxt/ {
    alias /var/www/mywebsite/site/.nuxt/dist/;
}
```

However, if `/_nuxt/` has stuff that may have to be `proxy_pass`'ed to the upstream, and you want to continue using the [pcre](http://ports.su/devel/pcre)-based `location` you already have had in your original config, then an ***alternative solution*** like below is also an option (otherwise, you obviously would have to remove it as redundant, to make sure that the prior prefix-based location works, see http://nginx.org/r/location):

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|srt|swf)$ {
    rewrite ^/_nuxt(/.*) $1 break; 
    root /var/www/mywebsite/site/.nuxt/dist/;
}
```

Comment: Hi! After a few tries, it works… partially, because it also look for files in the root directory for static assets.

And I finally found why in an old, closed github issue. As I thought, this is totally on Nuxt: although the "static spa mode" is totally working effortless, the "ssr" mode seems to have pretty much nothing automated… They just expect us to build then upload certain folders and files on the server; files and folders not all found in the dist folder that has been built. And this is, oddly enough, not documented anywhere; and this is not what I expect at all from it.

Comment: But as your answer could have been a working and simple workaround, have the bounty reward, to thank you for the time you took looking at the problem. Thanks again!